# Following error show , how to fix it?

Tags: zend-framework2

[image]

Following Error Show , please tell me how to fix it ?

Comment: "Zend\I18n\Validator component requires the intl PHP extension" - copy that to google....

Comment: Man, seriously... it's written in the message!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your php.ini you should look for extension=php_intl.dll if its commented, comment that out,
check if your extension_dir= points to a valid location (probably yes) and finally make sure that your extension_dir contains php_intl.dll.